# Quickly, From B To H, Sextupled Pawns

Tags: optimization, chess

A couple of years ago, a question was [posed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56594/get-6-pawns-in-file-a-or-h) about the minimum number of moves to obtain sextupled pawns on the edge of a chess board. The accepted, and proven optimal, answer found 31.0 plies to be optimal for the h file. However, this left my wondering about the rest of the board.

What is the quickest way to obtain sextupled pawns on the b through h files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mayhematics.com, there is an electronic copy of the 10/1998 chess booklet [Synthetic Games](https://www.mayhematics.com/p/syntheticgames.pdf). Within it, on page 10, there is this snippet: "Rubin gives minima on other files: e 12, d 12 1/2, f 13, bg 15 1/2. The ah cases require 37 moves." The c file game is on the left side of the page.

This gives us data to match and/or break. Of course, the "ah cases" bit is already irrelevant. Both comments and edits are welcome.

I shall now list the current best scores, in plies, I have come across, whether through myself or sources.

*A File:* 31.0 plies, optimized, modified from a slightly longer setup on [flyga natten's blog.](https://zyxyvy.wordpress.com/2018/01/27/sextuple-rook-pawns-puzzle/)

> 1. a4 b5 2. axb5 a5 3. Rxa5 Bb7 4. b6 Na6 5. Rh5 Nh6 6. d4 Nf5 7. Bh6 Bd5 8. b7 Nc5 9. bxa8=Q gxh6 10. Qc6 Bg7 11. Qg6 Rf8 12. e4 fxg6 13. exf5 Be5 14. dxe5 Rf6 15. c4 Re6 16. cxd5 gxh5 17. dxe6 dxe6 18. b4 Qd6 19. bxc5 exf5 20. Qg4 fxg4 21. cxd6 cxd6 22. g3 dxe5 23. Bh3 gxh3 24. f4 exf4 25. Nf3 fxg3 26. Ng5 gxh2 27. Rf1 Kd8 28. Rf6 exf6 29. Nd2 fxg5 30. Nf3 Ke8 31. Nh4 gxh4

*B File:* 17.0 plies, not optimized.

> 1. d4 e6 2. Be3 f6 3. d5 exd5 4. Bb6 cxb6 5. e4 a6 6. Bb5 axb5 7. c4 dxc4 8. a3 Bb4+ 9. axb4 d6 10. Qd5 Ne7 11. Qc5 dxc5 12. e5 fxe5 13. Ne2 cxb4 14. Nd4 exd4 15. Nc3 dxc3 16. Ra3 cxb2 17. Rb3 cxb3

*C File:* 11.5 plies, optimized, from the booklet.

> 1. a4 b5 2. b4 e5 3. f4 Bc5 4. fxe5 d6 5. exd6 Nc6 6. dxc7 Qd3 7. axb5 Be6 8. exd3 Bc4 9. dxc4 Nf6 10. bxc6 Ne4 11. bxc5 Nc3 12. dxc3

*D File:* 13.0 plies, not quite optimized.

> 1. b4 a5 2. e4 axb4 3. c4 b5 4. d4 bxc4 5. Bd3 cxd3 6. Ne2 f6 7. e5 fxe5 8. Nec3 bxc3 9. Ba3 exd4 10. Bd6 exd6 11. Qb3 c6 12. Qd5 cxd5 13. Nd2 cxd2+

*E File:* 13.0 plies, not quite optimized.

> 1. g4 h5 2. d4 hxg4 3. f4 g5 4. e4 gxf4 5. Be3 fxe3 6. Nd2 c6 7. d5 cxd5 8. Ndf3 gxf3 9. Bh3 dxe4 10. Be6 dxe6 11. Ne2 fxe2 12. Qd5 f6 13. Qe5 fxe5

*F File:* 13.0 plies, optimzed.

> 1. f4 e5 2. e4 d5 3. d4 exf4 4. Bd3 dxe4 5. Nf3 exf3 6. Bg6 hxg6 7. Be3 c5 8. g4 Bf5 9. gxf5 cxd4 10. Rf1 dxe3 11. Qd4 gxf5 12. Qf6 gxf6 13. Rf2 exf2+

*G File:* 17.0 plies, not optimized.

> 1. e4 d6 2. Bd3 c6 3. e5 dxe5 4. Bg6 fxg6 5. d4 h6 6. Bg5 hxg5 7. Qf3 Bg4 8. Qf6 exf6 9. h3 f5 10. hxg4 fxg4 11. d5 cxd5 12. Nd2 Kd7 13. Ne4 dxe4 14. f4exf4 15. Nf3 exf3 16. Rh3 fxg2 17. Rg3 fxg3

Answer (score 1):

I found a faster way to get 6 pawns on the B-File than your 21-move solution. This is probably not optimal though.

PGN:

```
1. b4 c5 2. d4 cxb4 3. d5 e6 4. Nd2 exd5
5. Nc4 dxc4 6. Rb1 f6 7. Rb3 cxb3 8. Qd6 g6
9. Qc6 dxc6 10. e4 h6 11. Bb5 cxb5 12. Bb2 Kf7
13. a4 Kg7 14. e5 fxe5 15. Nf3 Kh7 16. Nd4 exd4
17. c3 dxc3 18. a5 cxb2 19. Ke2 Qb6 20. axb6 axb6
```

[Link here](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=b4_c5_d4_cxb4_d5_e6_Nd2_exd5_Nc4_dxc4_Rb1_f6_Rb3_cxb3_Qd6_g6_Qc6_dxc6_e4_h6_Bb5_cxb5_Bb2_Kf7_a4_Kg7_e5_fxe5_Nf3_Kh7_Nd4_exd4_c3_dxc3_a5_cxb2_Ke2_Qb6_axb6_axb6)